# Yammer developer - Delete all access tokens for an application

Tags: rest, api, oauth-2.0, access-token, yammer

How to delete all access tokens that have been generated for an application.

I tried to revoke access for that application but still I can access data through existing application token.

Answer (score 0):

On your edit account page, you can go to "My Applications" and click "Revoke Access".